# Elastic GeoHash Query - Aggregation Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, geohashing

I am trying to query an elastic index where the result of the query is a list of the geohashes with only one matching document.

I can get a simple list of all geo hashes and their document counts using the following:

`{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggregations" : {
        "boundingbox" : {
            "filter" : {
                "geo_bounding_box" : {
                    "location" : {
                        "top_left" : "34.5, -118.9",
                        "bottom_right" : "33.3, -116."
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggregations":{
                "grid" : {
                    "geohash_grid" : {
                        "field": "location",
                        "precision": 4
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

However I can't work out the correct syntax to filter the query, the closest I can get are below:

This fails with 503 `org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.filter.InternalFilter cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.InternalMultiBucketAggregation`

`` "aggregations":{
    "grid" : {
        "geohash_grid" : {
            "field": "location",
            "precision": 4
        }
    },
    "grid_bucket_filter" : {
        "bucket_selector" : {
            "buckets_path" :{
                "docCount" : "grid" //Also tried `"docCount" : "doc_count"`
            },
            "script" : "params.docCount == 1"
        }
    }
} ``

This fails with 400 `No aggregation found for path [doc_count]`

`"aggregations":{
    "grid" : {
        "geohash_grid" : {
            "field": "location",
            "precision": 4
        }
    },
    "grid_bucket_filter" : {
        "bucket_selector" : {
            "buckets_path" :{
                "docCount" : "doc_count"
            },
            "script" : "params.docCount > 1"
        }
    }
}`

How can I filter based on the `doc_count` in a geohash grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it like this, i.e. the bucket selector pipeline shall be specified as a sub-aggregation of the `geohash_grid` one. Plus you need to use `_count` instead of `doc_count`(see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#_special_paths)):

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "grid": {
      "geohash_grid": {
        "field": "location",
        "precision": 4
      },
      "aggs": {
        "grid_bucket_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "docCount": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.docCount > 1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```